# Como crear log en c# para cada proceso

Tags: c#

Hola estoy realizando un Windows servicie lo cual esta temporizado para cada hora ejecutarse pero al realizar el log que muestro genera en el mismo txt , en este caso como realizaría  cuando se ejecute se cree un nuevo txt y evitar que se registro todo en uno mismo. C#

```
    private void WriteToFile(string Message)
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            else
            {
                
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }  
    }
```

Comment: Deberias añadir tambien la hora, minutos y segundos en el nombre del archivo para que no te reemplace el archivo que ya tienes creado y sean todo nombres diferentes.

Comment: Otra opción a la que comenta @Marc es añadir un numero secuencial al final del archivo de texto